# Can't ping gateway or access outside internet from Ubuntu guest on Windows 10 host

Tags: windows, networking, linux-networking, virtual-machines, virtualbox

Using Virtualbox Version 6.1.16 r140961 (Qt5.6.2) on Windows 10 Home host. When using Bridged Adapter mode on a Ubuntu 20.10 server vm.

I am unable to ping the gateway from the guest. I can ping from the guest to the host and vice versa. However pinging the gateway or the outside internet is not possible. If i switch to NAT i can access the internet. I would like to use the Bridged Adapter mode.

I tried turning off the windows firewall and still no go. When i logged into the router admin panel, i noticed there were no entries in the users list for the guest ip address. I am thinking the Windows Host is somehow configured incorrectly or is preventing access.

Both the guest and the host are on the same subnet, i also tried clearing the arp cache on the windows host as well.

I tried turning off the windows firewall and reinstalling virtual box using administrator rights and only selecting the bridged network adapter to install.

What else should i try?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic here. We do not accept questions about home computers or home networks or end user support. You may be able to get help on our sister site [su].

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have the same issue on my work laptop which is on the same "home" network. As i am working from from home like most folks these days, that line of work/home has been blurred. I will ask on there as well.

Comment: @dan sorry but Michael is handling this correctly i raised also a flag as if this might be business related you would know how to route and nat this

Comment: I found out that this is due to my router, since the problem does not occur at my friends house and he has a different router.

Comment: @dan then get a better one or i belive this is as i mentioned not business related question and is not supported pn serverfault.com, please move forward with this one to superuser.com

Comment: @djdomi Some people might find this useful, maybe they haven't thought about checking their router as a problem source. Regardless where this question was asked, folks find content on the internet in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a couple of quick workarounds you can try and hopefully, that can works for you.

[https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-fix-a-virtualbox-bridged-network-issue/#:~:text=Open%20VirtualBox%2C%20select%20one%20of,to%20Bridged%20(Figure%20A).&text=Even%20if%20you%20change%20providers,allow%20traffic%20into%20the%20VM](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-fix-a-virtualbox-bridged-network-issue/#:%7E:text=Open%20VirtualBox%2C%20select%20one%20of,to%20Bridged%20(Figure%20A).&text=Even%20if%20you%20change%20providers,allow%20traffic%20into%20the%20VM).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922055/bridged-networking-not-working-in-virtualbox-under-windows-10

Regrads!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i tried both but still have the same issue.